# How i show this beautiful inequality :$\frac{x^n}{x^m+y^m}+\frac{y^n}{y^m+z^m}+\frac{z^n}{z^m+x^m}\geq \frac{3} {2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{n-m}$?

Tags: inequalities

This question accross to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306593/230303) question from SE which there some answers but they r n't

enough to me hop to see MO what can they say about it .

let $m,n$ be integers, show that if $ n>m\geq 0 $ :

$$\frac{x^n}{x^m+y^m}+\frac{y^n}{y^m+z^m}+\frac{z^n}{z^m+x^m}\geq \frac{3}
{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{n-m}$$

where real $x,y,z > 0 $ and $xy + yz + zx = 1$

Note : The question is Already montioned [here](http://mathproblems-ks.com/?wpfb_dl=59) in journal k.s competition prolem 111.

**Edit** :The  choice of $x, y ,z$ gaven by peterMuller, does not fulfill the auxiliary condition $xy+yz+zx=1$ as it is required in the problem, so it cannot serve as a counter example. In any case, even with him choice of $x,y,z,$ he still need to show it is less than $\sqrt{3}/2$, since this is the claim in the problem

Thank you for your help .

Comment: Where did you find this inequality?

Comment: Might look a bit less messy if you let $X=\sqrt3x$, $Y=\sqrt3y$, and $Z=\sqrt3z$. That gets rid of the $(1/\sqrt3)^{n-m}$ on the right, at the cost of changing the boundary condition to $XY+YZ+ZX=3$.

Comment: Feels like a math competition inequality...

Comment: Thank you for waiting until *after* the date for submitting solutions before posting here.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, but why this downvote to my uestion such that i hput it source ?

Answer (score 17):

This inequality doesn't hold in general. It is false for instance for $m=7$, $n=8$: Set $X=3/4$, $Y=1$, and $Z=9/7$. Then $XY+YZ+ZX=3$, however $\frac{X^8}{X^7+Y^7}+\frac{Y^8}{Y^7+Z^7}+\frac{Z^8}{Z^7+X^7}<\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: you can check this :http://mathproblems-ks.com/?wpfb_dl=59 problem 110

Comment: Aha, so the math competition problem there isn't correct. By the way, you should have told the source of this question, and given a reason to post it at MO.

Comment: sorry for this , but since you have got a counterexample and it is work i think no problem to say that is true

Comment: Peter is right. We generally don't do competition problems, and there are good reasons we don't. Thus if you submit a competition problem, you should always disclose the source of the problem and explain why an exception should be made, as a courtesy. You were even asked earlier by GH from MO but decided not to respond; why?

Comment: @ToddTrimble,sorry i was offline for giving a response to GHfrom MO about source of this question and i posted it in MO after the date of submitting it to journal k.s.

Comment: And i'm confused how competition did a wrong like this however it were published by journal .

Comment: If you're wondering why I called it a "competition problem": it's a "competition" to see if one can solve the problem by one's self and get one's name in the journal; the "winners" are those that do, and first prize is to have one's solution be the one published as the official solution. We don't discuss that kind of thing here except in rare circumstances (usually because it ties in with a bona fide research question).

Comment: @ToddTrimble,why this downvote such that i edited the uestion putting it source ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I didn't downvote. I don't know who did or why.

Comment: @PeterMueller  Your choice of X, Y, Z, does not fulfill the auxiliary condition xy+yz+zx=1 as it is required in the problem, so it cannot serve as a counter example. In any case, even with your choice of x,y,z, you still need to show it is less than \sqrt{3}/2, since this is the claim in the problem

Comment: @ToddTrimble,hop you to reopen the question because it is not a counter-example as i showed to Petermueller

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Peter Mueller's answer uses Joe Silverman's equivalent reformulation of the problem.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, so you meant this problem is wrong under :xy+yz+zx=1 condition ?

Comment: Yes, the inequality in your post seems to be incorrect as stated. I just went through Peter's example and the arithmetic checks out.

Comment: @PeterMueller, i'm regret your solution to this problem  is wrong , pleas   see the solution under xy+yz+zx=1  ,page 374 by the proposer and paolo parfeti :https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wjbj058iq0ffly/Mathproblem.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I don't care about the two ``proofs'' if there is a simple counterexample. As you don't seem to be able to understand the simple reformulation (suggested by Silverman), here is the example in the original setting: Set $x=\frac{3}{4\sqrt{3}}$, $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $z=\frac{9}{7\sqrt{3}}$. Then $xy+yz+zx=1$, and with $m=7$, $n=8$, $\frac{x^n}{x^m+y^m}+\frac{y^n}{y^m+z^m}+\frac{z^n}{z^m+x^m}-\frac{3}{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{n-m}=-\frac{30373554930137225}{11449504266834352656}\sqrt{3}<0$.

Comment: @PeterMueller ,      no, i understood well the reformulation of silvermen , but i'm chocked by the proofs of parfeti and proposer of problem in journal which worked under xy+yz+zx=1.pleas let me know who is true u or journal ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Are you really unable to check if my examples are counter examples or not? At http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306593/how-i-show-this-beautiful-inequality-fracxnxmym-fracynymzm/1572042 I've added a second dis-proof which does not require to compute with large integers.